# If two posets have same dense open sets, are they equivalent as notions of forcing?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Suppose that $\mathbb{P}_0=(P,\leq_0)$ and $\mathbb{P}_1=(P,\leq_1)$ are partial orderings (in the weak sense, i.e., reflexive and transitive relations) on the same underlying set $P$, and such that $\leq_0$ is stronger than $\leq_1$, i.e., $p\leq_0q$ implies $p\leq_1 q$. Note that this implies that any $\leq_0$-dense subset $D$ of $P$ is also $\leq_1$-dense.

Suppose, moreover, that whenever $D$ is a $\leq_1$-dense open subset of $P$, it is also $\leq_0$-dense. Note that then, any $M$-generic filter $G$ for $\mathbb{P}_0$ generates an $M$-generic filter for $\mathbb{P}_1$.

My question is, are $\mathbb{P}_0$ and $\mathbb{P}_1$ equivalent as notions of forcing? The key issue seems to be that incompatibility need not be preserved in the passage from $\leq_0$ to $\leq_1$.

Comment: Reflexive + transitive = preorder. Not partial order.

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, how did you stumble upon this question?

Comment: I have two posets (well, preorders) where one is essentially a quotient of the other and has the aforementioned property, though I need to double check this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - let $\mathbb{P}=2^{<\omega}$ with the usual ordering, $\mathbb{P}_0=\mathbb{P}\setminus\{\emptyset\}$, and $\mathbb{Q}$ be the lottery sum of $\mathbb{P}_0$ and the one-point forcing. Then - identifying the "dull point" of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the empty string - $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ have the same underlying set, and the same dense open subsets$^*$, but are clearly not equivalent.

I suspect this type of counterexample can be modified to get something less trivial.

---

$^*$Specifically, if $D\subseteq\mathbb{P}$ is dense and open, then $\emptyset\in D$ and $D\cap \mathbb{P}_0$ is dense open in $\mathbb{P}_0$. Meanwhile, a dense open in $\mathbb{Q}$ is precisely the "dull point" together with a dense open subset of $\mathbb{P}_0$.

Comment: Forestalling possible confusion: no, "dull point" is not actual terminology so far as I know, it's just what I use when thinking about constructions like this.

Comment: What is a lottery sum?

Comment: @user254665 Think "disjoint sum." Just put them side by side - so no element of one side is comparable with an element of the other. Basically, the generic filter has to "choose" whether to be generic for one or the other piece of the sum.

Comment: Nothing wrong with trivial counterexamples, for me. I also like this terminology "lottery sum".

Comment: How are they not equivalent for forcing? It seems to me that the set of forcing extensions using $ P$ co-incides the set of forcing extensions using  $P_0.$ What am I not seeing?

Comment: @user254665 $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{P}_0$ are equivalent - the pair I was talking about was $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. A generic extension by $\mathbb{Q}$ *might* be a $\mathbb{P}$-extension . . . or it might be trivial (i.e. just $V$ itself).

Comment: The way I describe lottery sums is as an iteration: first you choose the forcing, then you force with it.

Comment: @Noah Schweber. I meant P and Q. I just didn't see it : The set containing just the dull point is a generic filter ! +1.